# Where should 了 go: 你去了商店买什么衣服？ or 你去商店买什么衣服了？

Tags: grammar, sentence-structure, particles, past-tense

I want to ask, "What clothes did you buy at the store?"
Which sentence is correct, or which sounds more correct.

> 你去了商店买什么衣服？
>
> 你去商店买什么衣服了？

Where should the 了 go?

Comment: I found [this YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5mnag_q--oU) a good introduction to 了.

Answer (score 1):

了 following a 'verb' is a 'verb particle' that indicates the 'verb' as 'completed'

In "你去了商店买什么衣服？" (You went to the store to buy what kind of clothes)  '了' following the verb '去'(go), therefore, indicated '去' as a completed action (went/ have gone to)

In "你去商店买什么衣服了？" 了 is mostly treated as a final particle, therefore may not clearly indicate what action is completed

> "What clothes did you buy at the store?"

If you want to mark the verb '买' (buy) as a completed action, you need to put the verb particle 了 after it.

> "你去商店[**买了**]什么衣服？" = You went to the store and [**bought**] what?

You can even add a final particle 了 at the end to emphasize the sentence --  "你去商店[**买了**]什么衣服了？"